# Cannot recover from typo in /etc/pam.d/sudo

Tags: sudo, pam, macos

I used to have fingerprint authentication support in my `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file by following [this article](https://www.imore.com/how-use-sudo-your-mac-touch-id); however, I made a typo in the file, spelling `pam_tid.so` as `pam.tid.so` and so now when I run `sudo` from the terminal, I get the following error:

```
sudo: unable to initialize PAM: No such file or directory
```

How can I recover from this? I have tried to go into recovery mode into the command line, but the `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file doesn't even exist from there.

Comment: you do not have root access?

Comment: @binarysta yes I do. in recovery mode but the file doesn't exist. in the terminal I'm just logged in as my user and can't use sudo because I messed up the file

Comment: why not using `su -` and change the file name with root privileges ?

Comment: Thanks @binarysta. That did the trick. I couldn't do it at first but it turns out it's because the root user was disabled.

Comment: Good! so you enabled root in rescue mode and then renamed the file?

Comment: Thankfully I was able to do it without logging out of the system, following this article by Apple: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012

Answer (score 10):

You can also reveal the file in the folder and change the permissions there.

```bsh
open /etc/pam.d/
```

[image: Permission change]

Make sure to reset the permissions afterwards again.

Comment: Thanks. This was a life-saver.